# Add data to a form in `CreateView`

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I have a model which the user submits on a form, and I would like to handle that form with a `CreateView`. However, there is one field in the model which the user doesn't provide, which is their IP address.

The problem is that the  `CreateView` fails with an `IntegrityError` since the field is empty. I tried modifying `request.POST` to add the relevant field, but that's not allowed (and a bad idea).

I figured I could use a hidden input on the form and put the IP there but that means the user can blank it or modify it if they like, I want the exact IP that did the `POST` request.

If I understand correctly both the `form_valid` and `form_invalid` methods are too early in the process, since the object hasn't been created yet? Is there any other way of doing this?

Here is what the code looks like:

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    text = models.TextField()
```

and the view:

```
class AnswerForm(CreateView):
    template_name = "answer.html"
    model = Answer
    success_url = reverse_lazy('answer')
    fields = ['text']
```

Comment: Can you get the users IP in the view? Please add your model and view to the question. And no `form_valid` is not too early, you can do what you want there.

Comment: Can you add your form code ?

Comment: Hi @Guillaume and abdul-aziz-barkat, I've added the code as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request data is stored in the object itself, therefore you can access it as such:

```
class AnswerForm(CreateView):
    template_name = "answer.html"
    model = Answer
    success_url = reverse_lazy('answer')
    fields = ['text']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.ip_address = get_ip_address(self.request)
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```